# How to stop rails from parsing json postgresql field to hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql, activerecord

I am in search of a way to tell rails to parse json and jsonb data from postgresql column to a different Class or simply stop it from parsing it to an Hash as I won't use the hash.

I use`read_attribute_before_type_cast`,
but the type cast is wasteful for my application.

Thank you

Comment: Try to specify `String` type: `serialize :your_field, String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my finding, it is not complete but solve my problem. I wrotte/found a serializer to deal with the json column.

In the model:

```
serialize :profile, HashSerializer
```

And the serializer is defined like this:

```
class HashSerializer
  def self.dump(hash)
    hash.to_json
  end

  def self.load(hash)
    (hash || {}).with_indifferent_access
  end
end
```